# Relation between MapReduce and Divde and Conquer

Tags: parallel-processing, mapreduce, divide-and-conquer

Is Map Reduce a real Divide and Conquer? Some says simply yes and other says no, it is a pipelining.

What do you think about the following:

They closely related but one can be a special case of the other:

Map Reduce involves a reduce process which is not obligatory in Divide and Conquer
We can say that Map Reduce is a special case of Divide and Conquer that involves a reduce phase.
Other Divide and Conquer problems that has nothing to reduce (eg. binary search) is a Map Reduce that has a dummy/trivial reduce process.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it should be understood in that manner. Yes, Mar-Reduce is more about segregation and aggregation. A map-reduce program can be written which has only one mapper running and it outputs directly to the hdfs rather than needing a Reducer to do so. 
Also, the number of mapper is dependent on the size of data, not the data itself. By default it has 1 mapper per 64MB (approx) but can be set to a much larger amount then removing any question of division of data.

This [book](http://lintool.github.io/MapReduceAlgorithms/) very nicely discusses history of Map Reduce and is suggested for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks @Piyush, I might have tackled the issue in manner that is affected by one opinion. What is needed to be clarified: Does MapReduce concept (generally) belongs to the divide and conquer technique?